# Efficient mass modification of persistent data structures

Tags: data-structures, immutability

I understand how typically trees are used to modify persistent data structures (create a new node and replace all it's ancestors).

But what if I have a tree of 10,000's of nodes and I need to modify 1000's of them? I don't want to go through and create 1000's of new roots, I only need the one new root that results from modifying everything at once.

For example:
Let's take a persistent binary tree for example. In the single update node case, it does a search until it finds the node, creates a new one with the modifications and the old children, and creates new ancestors up to the root.

In the bulk update case could we do:
Instead of just updating a single node, you're going to update 1000 nodes on it in one pass.

At the root node, the current list is the full list. You then split that list between those that match the left node and those that match the right. If none match one of the children, don't descend to it. You then descend to the left node (assuming there were matches), split its search list between its children, and continue. When you have a single node and a match, you update it and go back up, replacing and updating ancestors and other branches as appropriate.

This would result in only one new root even though it modified any number of nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These kind of "mass modification" operations are sometimes called *bulk updates*.  Of course, the details will vary depending on exactly what kind of data structure you are working with and what kind of modifications you are trying to perform.

Typical kinds of operations might include "delete all values satisfying some condition" or "increment the values associated with all the keys in this list".  Frequently, these operations can be performed in a single walk over the entire structure, taking O(n) time.

You seem to be concerned about the memory allocation involved in creating "1000's of new roots".  Typical allocation for performing the operations one at a time would be O(k log n), where k is the number of nodes being modified.  Typical allocation for performing the single walk over the entire structure would be O(n).  Which is better depends on k and n.

In some cases, you can decrease the amount of allocation--at the cost of more complicated code--by paying special attention to when changes occur.  For example, if you have a recursive algorithm that returns a tree, you might modify the algorithm to return a tree *together with* a boolean indicating whether anything has changed.  The algorithm could then check those booleans before allocating a new node to see whether the old node can safely be reused.  However, people don't usually bother with this extra check unless and until they have evidence that the extra memory allocation is actually a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. I wasn't considering walking over the entire structure. I added an example in the question. It seems to me that this example would have a much smaller memory footprint than the 1 by 1 approach. With splitting the list at each branch, it might be similar to O(k log n) for search, but each node that is updated (including ancestor nodes) is updated only once. 1 by 1 case: (k log n) to search for each node, but then another (k * avg depth) for updating ancestors (some repeatedly). In the question example, wouldn't that be reduced significantly?

Comment: Sure, your new binary tree example is essentially what I was referring to as walking the entire structure, because in general it will make recursive calls down both sides of the tree.  Of course, in special cases, you may be able to stop early and avoid traversing parts of the tree.  In other cases, you may still need to traverse part of the tree only to find that no changes actually happened in that part of the tree.  That's when the extra boolean return value I mentioned might be useful if you want to avoid unnecessary allocation.

Comment: You only walk down a branch if there are nodes to be updated that match that branch. It searches the exact same way as the 1 by 1 case, but it does all k searches at the same time. So you'll never need to return a boolean about whether it updated or not because you would not have gone down that branch to begin with unless it would be updated.

Comment: If you can tell by looking at a particular node that you don't have to do anything at either that node or any of its descendents, then you don't have to go into the node at all.  Often, however, you'll be able to tell that you don't have to do anything at the node itself, but won't necessarily know about the descendents, in which case you would probably need to traverse to the descendents anyway.

Comment: Given that we were talking about comparing to the O(k log n) case, I was assuming we were talking about the same type of operations, which means we would know exactly how to search and when to stop. The case where you don't know about the descendants generally requires an exhaustive search, so that has nothing to do with my question. In this bulk update question, we have a list of existing nodes and we either want to remove them, or modify a field in them, or in some way replace them with updated values.

Comment: Clojure addresses this question by providing *transient* versions of many of its collections. This is a temporary, local-only, mutable version of a persistent collection that allows a batch of operations with minimal allocation and copying of nodes.  When the batch of operations are done, before releasing the instance to the "public", it is converted back to an immutable persistent collection.  Conversion to and from transient are constant-time. You can read more about them here http://clojure.org/transients

Answer (score 3):

A particular implementation of what you're looking for can be found in Clojure's (and ClojureScript's) [transients](http://clojure.org/transients).

In short, given a fully-immutable, persistent data structure, a transient version of it will make changes using destructive (allocation-efficient) mutation, which you can flip back into a proper persistent data structure again when you're done with your performance-sensitive operations.  It is only at the transition back to a persistent data structure that new roots are created (for example), thus amortizing the attendant cost over the number of logical operations you performed on the structure while it was in its transient form.